# JSP dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: jsp, dynamic, html-select

I need to fill the dropdownlist according to selected field in another dropdownlist.How can i implement this? Here is my code :

```
                <tr>
                <td>CITY :</td>
                <td><select name="city">
                        <%
                            while (rs.next()) {
                        %>
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <%
            rs = db.runQuery(conn, "Select distinct town from adress where city='" + request.getParameter("city") +"'");
            %>
            <tr>
                <td>TOWN</td>
                <td><select name="town">
                        <%
                            while (rs.next()) {
                        %>
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                </select>
            <tr>
```

First dropdown fills correctly but second one does not work.How can i handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you cannot do it is that JSP compiles to Servlet and runs on server side. The Servlet runs only once before you select a city. I think the easiest solution is submitting the form twice:

```
<select name="city" onChange="this.form.submit();">
```

The nicer solution is using Ajax on client side, but that needs more JavaScript or some JavaScript libraries or JSP taglibs. jQuery is a pretty useful JavaScript framework for such tasks.

Comment: But there is problem.If i choose the first item of dropdown,form is not being submitted?Is there anyway to define to dropdown a default index to return?

Comment: I would add a new line before this: rs = db.runQuery(conn, "Select distinct town...     String city = request.getParameter("city"); and use (city!=null?city:"Defaultcity") in that line

Comment: but then there will be always default city in dropdownlist since form is reloaded after selecting operation?

Comment: you can also try adding a new default option to the first select: <option  selected="selected" value="<%=yourvalue%>">

Comment: I just realized that when form re-submitted the selected value of first dropdown changes to first index just because datas are beimng retrieved again and dropdown is re-filled.

Comment: Is there any other way except submitting form again?